# How to parse PDF streams in .Net

Tags: .net, pdf

I have some free C# code to parse PDF files, which I downloaded.

I have written code using these classes to extract information about the form fields, and generate a new PDF with the form fields populated.

Now I've discovered that it doesn't work with new PDF's, because new PDF's have streams where the old formats had plain text.  I don't have the time to study the PDF format documentation and write my own PDF stream parser, so I'd like to know if anyone knows of a library or classes that I can use from C# / .Net.

Before you say "Use iTextSharp", the problem with iTextSharp is the license.  I need code that can be used in commercial software.  If you're unsure about the license, let me know anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: IText will sell you a commercial license if you ask them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [Docotic PDF Library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/). This library allows to fill in form fields with ease.

Here is a sample for your task:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

using BitMiracle.Docotic.Pdf;

namespace BitMiracle.Docotic.Samples
{
    public static class FillForm
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            using (var document = new PdfDocument("Some Document.pdf"))
            {
                ReadOnlyCollection<PdfWidget> widgets = document.Pages[0].Widgets;
    
                PdfTextBox textBox = (PdfTextBox)widgets[0];
                textBox.Text = "Some Name";
    
                PdfCheckBox checkBox = (PdfCheckBox)widgets[1];
                checkBox.Checked = true;
    
                PdfRadioButton firstRadioButton = (PdfRadioButton)widgets[2];
                firstRadioButton.Checked = false;
    
                PdfRadioButton secondRadioButton = (PdfRadioButton)widgets[3];
                secondRadioButton.Checked = true;
    
                document.Save("FillForm.pdf");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aspose's PDF kit seems to do the job.  Hmmm... so I answer my own question... oh, well, if anyone knows any more, I'm still keen to hear about them.